# Selenium Grid stuck after "Registering the node to hub". It does not show any line as "Executing..."

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I'm facing a strange problem: I'm trying to set up a hub on a my window machine and node on VM or switch them.

But if I use the exact same commands to start the hub on my test VM the registration process seems to take forever.
Normally, the node should receive status request and respond to the hub server. But the console stays blank after printing
and when i click on myip:4444/grid/register it show me error like :-
HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /grid/register. Reason:

```
Server Error
```

=========================================
I am using combination as :-

Command (window 7):
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -host ip -role hub -port 4444

Command (ubuntu linux):
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -host ip -role node -hub ip:4444/grid/register -port 5555

====================================================

I also have tried :-
Command (window 7):
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub

Command (ubuntu linux):
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role webdriver -hub ip:4444/grid/register -port 5566

===================================================

I also have tried :-
Command (window 7):
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub

Command (ubuntu linux):
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub hubip:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,platform=LINUX -remoteHost nodeip:5555 -maxSession 5

[image]

Comment: done it by ref :- http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html

Comment: Does your windows have a firewall? If so, check whether that is disabled.

Comment: You are accessing (clicking on) `ip:4444/grid/register`? I thought that page expected a JSON object and to check nodes you went to `ip:4444/grid/console`

Answer (score 1):

That is how it is supposed to look like. The node is registered. You are good to go.

To view the grid settings, go to http://localhost:4444/grid/console

With Selenium Server Standalone 2.47.1, you will see better information at the end in the command prompt.

When hub is configured : INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running

When node is registered : INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use